# Hotter/Colder Number Game in Python

Tags: python

I'm working my way through the Code Academy Python course and have been trying to build small side projects to help reinforce the lessons.

I'm currently working on a number game. I want the program to select a random number between 1 and 10 and the user to input a guess.

Then the program will return a message saying you win or a prompt to pick another higher/lower number.

My code is listed below. I can't get it to reiterate the process with the second user input.

**I don't really want an answer, just a hint.**

```
import random
random.seed()

print "Play the Number Game!"
x = raw_input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 10:")
y = random.randrange(1, 10, 1)

#Add for loop in here to make the game repeat until correct guess?
if x == y:
    print "You win."
    print "Your number was ", x, " and my number was ", y
elif x > y:
    x = raw_input("Your number was too high, pick a lower one: ")
elif x < y:
    x = raw_input("Your number was too low, pick a higher one: ")
```

Comment: have a look here, if you're still stuck post your updated attempts: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Loops,_Conditionals

Comment: `#Add for loop in here to make the game repeat until correct guess?` - Have you tried that? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: One hint: You have to convert `x` to an integer.

Comment: `random.randrange(1, 10, 1)` will _only_ generate numbers that are greater than or equal to 1 and _less than_ 10. It's simpler to use `random.randint(1, 10)`, as suggested by Kevin Guan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use a `while` loop like `while x != y:`. [Here is more info about the while loop.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

And you can only use

```
import random
y = random.randint(1, 10)
```

instead other `random` function.

And I think you should learn about `int()` function [at here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

These are my hints :)

```
import random
n = random.randint(1, 10)
g = int(raw_input("Enter a whole number between 1 and 10: "))

while g != n:

    if g > n:
        g = int(raw_input("Your number was too high, pick a lower one: "))

    elif g < n:
        g = int(raw_input("Your number was too low, pick a higher one: "))

else:
    print "You win."
    print "Your number was ", g, " and my number was ", n
```

Comment: Ok, I added my updated code. The program correctly tells you whether its high or low, but then it just keeps defaulting to "too high" every time after that.

Comment: `int(g)` on its own will not do anything. You need to assign the result back to `g`. This might be very confusing for beginners.

Comment: @ZachHoyle try this program now :)

Comment: @EmilVikström that was confusing for me.

Comment: @KevinGuan it worked! Thank you. I'm working through code academy but often get sidetracked and try to make things a little outside of my skill level. Thanks for your advice and help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ZachHoyle He means that `int(g)` will convert `g` to `int`. But then, it will be throw away. So you have to use `g = int(g)`(or like my code). For example: try `a = 10 ; print a ; a + 10 ; print a ; a = a + 10 ; print a`.